# se puede añadir efectos de javascript a un solo div de la pagina

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

quisiera añadir los efectos de javascript para que solo funcionen en el div que tiene la linea del tiempo vertical y que no afecten a toda la pagina, solo a esa sección. Como puedo hacer por favor. Gracias.

Comment: Podrias agregar tu codigo

Comment: Lo puedes haber con un selector (Por Id, por clase....)

Comment: te recomiendo leer : https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Lo que debes hacer, es utilizar un identificador en el div que deseas modificar. Sí agregas el código de lo que intentaste, sería mucho más sencillo darte una respuesta más concreta..

Comment: Bienvenida. Las buenas preguntas en este sitio incluyen una breve descripción de lo buscado/investigado, usualmente mencionan lo que han intentado y señalan claramente dónde se quedaron "atorados" o un problema específico. Por favor edita tu pregunta para hacerla una buena pregunta. Ref. [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Necesitarias algo como esto:

```
$("#id-de-tu-div").click(function () {
    --Esto es un ejemplo de selector--
  });
```

Si quisieras que fuera un div dentro del header, por ejemplo:

```
$("header #id-de-tu-div").click(function () {
    --Esto es un ejemplo de selector--
  });
```

Estos ejemplos estan hechos con JQuery. En javascript deberia ser parecido.

Comment: Esta respuesta implica el uso de jQuery pero no lo mencionas